# Datatables (Server-side) - After formatting the artist data, its values is not searchable

Tags: php, search, datatables, server-side

I fetched data from the database. example of artist data is 10,11,12 (comma separated values), each values have their corresponding data from another table. 
After formatting and getting the values, all the data from the artist column is not searchable. 
I hope you understand what i'm trying to say.
Now my question is how to make my artist data searchable? Thank you in advance.
here's my code for the columns array:

```
$columns = array(
array('db' => '`t`.`track_id`', 'dt' => 0, 'formatter' => function($a){return '<a href="tracks-view.php?id='.$a.'">'.$a.'</a>';}, 'field' => 'track_id'),
array('db' => '`t`.`upc`', 'dt' => 1, 'field' => 'upc'),
array('db' => '`t`.`isrc`', 'dt' => 2,       'field' => 'isrc'),
array('db' => '`t`.`tracktitle`', 'dt' => 3, 'field' => 'tracktitle'),
array('db' => '`t`.`artist`', 'dt' => 4,
  'formatter' => function($a,$row){
          if($a !=''){
                  $ab = explode(',',$a);
                      $artist ="";
                      $db = new Database();
                      $db->connect();
                      foreach ($ab as $artindex => $artvalue) {
                        $q_a ='SELECT fname FROM rartist WHERE id = '.$artvalue;
                        $r_a = $db->query($q_a);
                        $a_a = $db->fetch_array_assoc($r_a);
                        $a_id = $artvalue;
                        $a_name = $a_a['fname'];
                        if(end($ab)==$artvalue){
                          $artist .= '<span>'.$a_name.'</span>';
                        }else{
                          $artist .= '<span>'.$a_name.'</span>, ';
                        }
                      }
                      return $artist;
          }else{return $artist='';}
        },
 'field' => 'artist'),
array('db' => '`t`.`publisher`', 'dt' => 5, 'field' => 'publisher'),
array('db' => '`t`.`licensor`', 'dt' => 6,  'field' => 'licensor'),
array('db' => '`t`.`genre`', 'dt' => 7, 'field' => 'genre'),
array('db' => '`t`.`discno`', 'dt' => 8, 'field' => 'discno'),
array('db' => '`t`.`trackno`', 'dt' => 9, 'field' => 'trackno')
);
```

any answer is highly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Are you trying search the data on the client-side or server-side?  I don't see anything in your SQL that would do that.

Comment: hi mark, I wan't the user to search the data on the client-side. Please help me. Thank you,